If a group doesn't have proper subgroups of finite index then G/G' is divisible
I wonder why if a group G (that is not perfect) doesn't have any proper subgroups of finite index then the quotient $G/G'$ is divisible. I get it must be infinite abelian, and i get that the opposite is true (if $G/G'$ is divisible then G doesn't have proper subgroups of finite index) but why can't it have a reduced direct factor? I assume that a reduced group always has a proper subgroup of finite index, but can't figure out why, and there's not much around about reduced groups.
Then i find this answer Classification of all groups up to Isomorphism having no proper non trivial subgroup of finite index. where it says that "obviously $G/G^n$ has subgroups of finite index". Why's that?
